# Can I use Salt instead of plain text password in a Passport Strategy?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Here is my Passport js local strategy:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = function() {
    // Use local strategy
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                //username: new RegExp(username, 'i')
                username: String(username).toLowerCase()
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('ERR: ', err);
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
                    });
                }
                if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
                    });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
};
```

I need to re-authenticate my users in a webview (not browser) using email and salted password (stored in localStorage).

What would I change in this strategy to use the hashed/salt password to re-authenticate a user? (or is that a terrible idea?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default with passportjs, your password will be salted + hashed and this result will be stored in your database, so you never use plain text password with this technology

Next, storing a password (even salted) in localstorage is a bad practice. You should only ask your user his password, and never store it ! The best way is to store a token and check if it's a valid one (jwt token are great)

one example : https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: Ah $h*t you're right. Here's a better approach I found using a sessionId to re-authenticate: http://justbuildsomething.com/cordova-and-express-session/